# Windows 11: Modify screensaver behavior via script

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-11, screensaver

I want to enable/disable the screensaver for a fixed local user via a scheduled task. My task runs

> `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /f /v ScreenSaverIsSecure /t REG_SZ /d 0`
>
> `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /f /v ScreenSaveActive /t REG_SZ /d 0`

and there is a corresponding "enable" task with 1 instead of 0 at the end.

The task runs as scheduled, and I can also run it manually. In both cases I can check with the registry editor that both keys in the registry have been changed. **But the screensaver settings do not change**.

I have confirmed that I am looking at the right settings by opening the "Screen Saver Settings" dialog and making changes there. Whenever I make a change, I can immediately see the change in the registry. But if I change the two keys above in the registry, whether manually or via script,  when I re open the "Screen Saver Settings" dialog the settings have not changed.

In this first screenshot, I first changed the two keys "ScreenSaveActive" and "ScreenSaverIsSecur" to 0 and then opened the screensaver settings dialog:

[image]

In this second screenshot, I deselected and re-selected "On resume, display logon screen" (so that there are changes to apply even though I'm not changing anything) and pressed "Apply". As can be seen the keys have changed:

[image]

As can be seen, I'm modifying the right keys, but the screensaver is not seeing the changes if they are made directly in the registry. Is there anywhere else where the screensaver's settings are saved, and where they are read from by the screen saver?

Comment: Have you tried restarting explorer after the script changes?

Comment: I did. No changes.

Comment: Try to add in this registry key an item named `SCRNSAVE.exe` with a dummy executable. ([link](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/turn-on-or-off-screen-saver-in-windows-11.8744/)).

Comment: @harrymc: That works perfectly, thanks! You should type that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for the poster is to sabotage the screensaver
by adding inside the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` a REG_SZ item named
`SCRNSAVE.exe`.

Setting the value of this item to a dummy "screensaver" program
effectively disabled the screensaver. It might be enough to set the
item to a null/empty value.

The effect of this registry change is immediate.

To undo, just delete this item.

---

Poster's report : After further experimentation I found that the change to `SCRNSAVE.EXE` alone is not enough to disable the screensaver. The change seemed to work to disable the screensaver when applied together with changing `ScreenSaveActive` and `ScreenSaverIsSecure` to 0.

Comment: What I ended up doing is to change the value to C:\WINDOWS\system32\scrnsavex.scr (note the x) to deactivate, and remove the x to activate.

Comment: Yes, of course. I was waiting a bit because on some SE sites it is considered bad etiquette to accept an answer too soon.

Comment: No problem. Thanks.

Comment: It turns out that that the change stopped working, and then I realized that I had removed the changes to the other keys from my script. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you - I have incorporated your input into my answer.